Python - Flask stops listening when put into child thread
I'm trying to use both PyQt5 and Flask on a Raspberry Pi to create a webserver/GUI combo. Both modules (to the best of my understanding) want to work in the main thread, but I found some articles online that said Flask could be run in a child thread. After I start the PyQt GUI in the main thread, Flask in the child thread stops accepting new connections.
Is there a better way to do handle the threading for these two modules, or is there a way that I can make sure that Flask continues to accept new connections?
My start script:
import threading
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import gui

app = Flask(__name__)

... (Flask GET/POST functions removed for readability) ...

def runServer():
    app.run(debug=True, user_reloader=False, port=5000, host="192.168.1.142")

t1 = threading.Thread(target=runServer)
t1.start()
gui.start()

Edit:
Start script:
#! /bin/bash

export MIXER_PATH=/home/volume/RPi-VM-GUI/
export FLASK_APP=server.py
cd $MIXER_PATH
flask run --host=192.168.1.142 --port=5000 &


Try adding the threaded=True keyword to app.run(). Also, it's use_reloader, not user_reloader.

@musicamante Thank you for the suggestions. I'm still failing to connect. Could it be the way I call the script? I've edited the question  with my start script

Unfortunately I've never used flask actively, so I cannot give you any further suggestions. You should probably do some research about how flask runs its own server. I suppose it has its own event loop, which should be able to process events while the main Qt one is idling, but that's just a guess.

The issue is with how I call the procedure. Previously, I would call
export FLASK_APP=server.py
flask run --host=192.168.1.142 --port=5000 &

to start running my flask server. I believe this was causing the PyQt to not run.
If I call the script directly and run app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, use_reloader=False, port=5000, host="192.168.1.142") from the my script, I can start the flask thread and PyQt at the same time and have them run concurrently.
If I call the procedure directly and not call flask, both PyQt and Flask will run concurrently
 /home/volume/RPi-VM-GUI/server.py

